# Ubuntu Software does not load applications

Tags: software-center, gnome-software

I have tried searching the net for a solution but I haven't come across this exact problem. When I open Ubuntu Software in 16.04 I see the "featured applications" "editors picks" "recommended" and "categories" But when I select any application nothing loads. I get the orange circle that keeps rotating and nothing ever happens, nothing ever loads.

The ONLY thing that temporarily solved this problem was:

```
$ killall gnome-software  
$ rm -r ~/.local/share/gnome-software
```

Once I ran the above everything loaded correctly in Ubuntu Software but it only lasted a few hours and eventually went back to the same old orange circle of death on everything I clicked.

Please help if you can :)

Comment: Before anything else, use a simple concatenated command to make sure your system is up-to-date: *sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade*. If you notice errors please edit and update your question will the full error messages.

Answer (score 1):

I have just answered a similar question.
This is a common thing. 
For me , I run bleachbit and reboot. That is the short answer.
You can also look at installing your .deb files with gdebi and the rest with synaptic package manager. Its a LOT faster.